# Assigning class observerimage load as public

Tags: java

Despite writing the codes, again and again, I m not able to run it and ending up with the following error
the code is as follows. please help me out with this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
        
public class ObserveImageLoad {

        public static void main (String[]args){
            ImageObserver myObserver = new ImageObserver() {
                public boolean imageUpdate(
                        Image image, int flags, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
                    if ((flags & HEIGHT) != 0) {
                        System.out.println("Image height = " + height);
                    }
                    if ((flags & WIDTH) != 0) {
                        System.out.println("Image width = " + width);
                    }
                    if ((flags & FRAMEBITS) != 0) {
                        System.out.println("Another frame finished.");
                    }
                    if ((flags & SOMEBITS) != 0) {
                        System.out.println("Image section :"
                                + new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
                    }
                    if ((flags & ALLBITS) != 0) {
                        System.out.println("Image finished!");
                    }
                    if ((flags & ABORT) != 0) {
                        System.out.println("Image load aborted...");
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            };

            Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            Image img = toolkit.getImage(args[0]);
            toolkit.prepareImage(img, -1, -1, myObserver);
        }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RECfy.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put class ObserveImageLoad in ObserveImageLoad.java, 
if a class declared with public , you have to put in  samename.java file

For example for my App.java file

```
// App.java file
public class App {
     //..
}
```

You can put more class in a .java file but there is only one public class which has same name with .java file